# Remove all special character from column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm working on MySQL and having column `phone-number`. And trying to use regex for this and not succeed.

How can I remove all special character from this column ?

```
phone-number
'8-903-400-65-38'
'+79265682388'
'8.10492E+15'
'8-913-469-38-35'
'+79882856253'
'+79110987703'
'+7 (495) 989-21-16'
'8142 77-55-51'
'+79378299427'
```

Please can anyone help me on this issue? I don't want to lose these list of contact numbers.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hyphen (`-`) is a special character in regex when used in a range, but I doubt you want to remove this.  Also, what in the world is `8.10492E+15`?  It looks like scientific notation, rather than a phone number.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I need only digits in this column and rest needs to be removed ..!!

Comment: What did you try so far? What regex did you use?

Answer (score 2):

The canned answer here is just to chain together a series of calls to MySQL's `REPLACE` function:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(phone-number, '-', ''), '+', ''), '.', ''), '(', ''), ')', ''), ' ', '')
```

This would remove the following characters from the `phone-number` column:

```
- + . ( ) and space
```

The nicer solution would be to use a regular expression to do the replacement, but alas MySQL does not any such built in support for regex replace.

If you don't want a fugly `REPLACE` chain, then you *could* write some dynamic MySQL code which iterates over a set of characters which you define, and does a number of updates to the table.  Here is what one such update would look like:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET phone-number = REPLACE(phone-number, '+', '')
```

You could perform one update for each character and handle it this way.

Comment: And what about alphabets ?

Comment: What is the source of your data?  I think you should handle this outside of MySQL.  If you give me enough details, I may be able to give you answer on this as well.

Comment: Its a data already on prod MYSQL db, now need some filtration like this mentioned above...So that's thing. Need to update this data on prod itself.